# JavaScript authentication JSONString: [object Object],[object Object]

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, parsing

I'm doing an authentication with

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: urlString,
     async: false,
     beforeSend: function(x) {
         },
     dataType: "json",
     username: "email@email.com",
     password: "password",
     success: function(data){
     returnData = data;
     }
});
```

And now I'm getting `" [object Object],[object Object]"` back. But actually I want to get `"[{"title":"Title1"},{"title":"Title2"}]"`. What's wrong? How can I see my information?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is normal to get an `Object` back as a response from the **ajax** **GET**. What you now have to do is to extract the required data from your object list like:

```
returnData = data;
$.each(returnData ,function(index,value){
console.log(value.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what information you get from an AJAX request, try the `console.log` function. You can use Firebug with Firefox, Dragonfly with Opera, or the original developer tools that comes with Chrome, Safari or IE.

```
...
success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
     returnData = data;
     }
...
```

Another solution would be to `string`ify your data, like so:

```
...
success: function(data){
     returnData = JSON.stringify(data);
     }
...
```

Check this out if you still have problems accessing your dev tools: http://vimeo.com/32947452

Comment: If `data` is an object then `data.toString()` will return `"[object Object]"`. A better idea might be to use `JSON.stringify(data)`.